# $wpdb->get_results with UNIONs in query

Tags: sql, wordpress, union

when running each of the following SELECTs on their own (without UNION) I´m getting results as expected. I don´t get any results when using UNION.

Any ideas why this doesn´t work?

```
$query = "
 (SELECT * FROM projects WHERE public='1')
 UNION
 (SELECT * FROM projects JOIN project_region ON projects.id_project = project_region.id_project 
 JOIN user ON user.id_region = project_region.id_region WHERE user.user_id = {$current_user->ID})
 UNION
 (SELECT * FROM projects JOIN project_user ON projects.id_project = project_user.id_project
 WHERE project_user.user_id = {$current_user->ID})
";

$projects = $wpdb->get_results($query);

if ($projects) {
   foreach ($projects as $project) {
      // output results
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `UNION` you need to have this same column number, column names for each union query. So in first query you have columns from projects table, but in second query you have columns from projects, project_region, and user tables.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but the problem was a MySQL error "Column 'id_project' in field list is ambiguous". See my answer below.

Comment: xto's answer is the right answer. joko13 your answer is the result of xto's explanation...

Answer (score 0):

The MYSQL error was *Column 'id_project' in field list is ambiguous*

So the working query looks like this:

```
$query = "
(SELECT id_project, name FROM projects WHERE public='1')
UNION
(SELECT projects.id_project, projects.name FROM projects JOIN project_region ON projects.id_project = project_region.id_project 
JOIN user ON user.id_region = project_region.id_region WHERE user.user_id = {$current_user->ID})
UNION
(SELECT projects.id_project, projects.name FROM projects JOIN project_user ON projects.id_project = project_user.id_project
WHERE project_user.user_id = {$current_user->ID})
";
```

i found the solution here:
http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/err918/mysql